# How to get the mulitple textbox values given at runtime in list

Tags: javascript, html

For example I have created the 4textbox for name and id in one page say example in indexview,in which i give the value at run time.I want to collect the values entered in the indexview page at runtime to be displayed in next page say as about page using list to be used in model and array to be used in jquery in mvc project.
Please anyone knows guide me

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand what you are asking. Could you please be a little bit more precise on what you have done, e.g. post the code, and what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you..

On first page  do this

```
  var getInput={Name:$("#nameId").val(),ID:("#id").val()};

  localStorage.setItem("key",JSON.stringify(getInput));

  location.href="nextPage.html";
```

On second page do this

```
  var getInput=JSON.parse(window.localstorage.getItem("key"));

  document.getElementById("someId").innerHTML=getInput.Name;
```

Like this you can send data from first page to another page.

Comment: please help me to do it for multiple textbox using list in model and arrays in jquery